# Reconfiguring SharePoint 2010 Portal 

Tags: administration, configuration

We have cloned the SharePoint 2010 Portal (WFE, App Server, Database) to create an Test environment. How do I reconfigure the WFE and App server(Central admin, service application, content databases etc.,) to point to the new database server.

Could someone provide me an guidance/best practice to accomplish this?

Comment: How did you clone it?

Comment: James, I checked with my systems engineer and he told me that he used vmware clone feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that you are wanting to basically clone then rename the server.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc261986.aspx

All the topology can be done from central administration afterwards.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shaden/archive/2007/07/05/moving-the-sharepoint-databases-to-a-new-sql-server-instance.aspx

Hope this helps.